# what does the やつ mean here?

Tags: meaning

悪魔には死んだ人の体を乗っ取れる**やつ**もいるらしい

My problem is the やつ. it feels useless, because there is 悪魔

"Demon can turn into bodies of dead people" but again there is やつ which feels like nonsense to me

Comment: How do you think いる works in that sentence? If the sentence means what you think it does, いる should also be “nonsense” to you.

Comment: Now that i think about it, yeah it is. Thats why i am asking. So i can get corrected on my interpretation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

やつ is actually a key word in the core part of the sentence.

1. Let's start by identifying that core.

> やつもいる: *Beings also exist.*

2. What kind of beings? Here's where we add a subordinate clause.

> 死んだ人の体を乗っ取れる: *That take over the bodies of people*

3. So what do we have so far?

> 死んだ人の体を乗っ取れるやつもいる: *Beings also exist that take over the bodies of people.*

4. We can leave things like this, or we could decide to be more specific about the types of beings we are talking about.

> 悪魔には: *Amongst demons*

5. So now we get...

> 悪魔には死んだ人の体を乗っ取れる**やつ**もいる: *Amongst demons, beings also exist that take over the bodies of people.* i.e. *Amongst demons, there are **those** that take over the bodies of people.*

**Removing やつ would be like removing the word "those."**

6. However, perhaps we are not completely sure about that fact.

> らしい: *It seems that...*

7. So in the end we get...

> 悪魔には死んだ人の体を乗っ取れるやつもいるらしい: *It seems that amongst demons, there are those that take over the bodies of people.* i.e. *Apparently, some demons can take over the bodies of dead people.*

Comment: Oh! i thought that the に is to mark what is doable to someone, 私にできる type of thing. but it turned out to be something way different, that made me not understand, thanks

Comment: That is just one of a very large number of uses of に. A quick look in the dictionary lists at least 8 basic uses for に, not to mention that we're talking about には in combination here, not just に in isolation.